# Java Spring factory dependent on other factory

Tags: java, spring

I have spring factory for list of classes which implement any interface:

```
@Service
public class ProjectServiceFactory{

    private List<IProjectService> projectServiceList;

    @Autowired
    public ProjectServiceFactory(List<IProjectService> projectServiceList){
        this.projectServiceList= projectServiceList;
    }

    public IProjectService provide(ProjectType projectType){
        Optional<IProjectService> service = this.projectServiceList.stream().filter(projectService-> projectServiceList.isTypeHandler(projectType)).findFirst();
        return service.get();
    }
}
```

Each implementation of IProjectService is dependent on different implementation of other interface - named IEntitiesDao. For example - see one of the implementations constructor:

```
@Service
public class CorrectionsProjectService implement IProjectService {

    @Autowired
    public CorrectionAssignmentsRiskCalculator(IEntitiesDao entitiesDao){
        super(entityListDao);
    }

    //class code...
}
```

So I need Spring to inject to each element in projectServiceList - other implementation of IEntitiesDao.
I have other factory - EntitiesDaoFactory, which know to return the match implementaion by ProjectType enum.
But where should I call this second factory?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to reinvent the entire Spring context implementation. Why do you need this "factory" (which isn't a factory, but a directory), instead of something like a `ProjectService<E extends ProjectType>`? (And it's not customary to use prefixes like `I` in Java.)

Comment: Can you please give an example? I don't understand how does it make new intance of each implementaion by current ProjectType

Comment: You aren't creating _anything_, you're just adding a new lookup mechanism that Spring can do for you if you make your `interface ProjectService` generic with `<E extends ProjectType>`.